# How to describe two variables in a heatmap?

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, data-tables, data, heatmaps

I need to describe distribution of showtimes across day-hours and their occupancy.

Showtimes distribution across day-hours can be described using a simple heatmap/ table, e.g.

[image: Showtime distribution]

Here each times-cell contains the number of showtimes on that hour. The color shows which hour has the most showtimes.

How do I add information about occupancy at every hour without losing the current information?

I am considering splitting the cell diagonally, e.g.

[image: diagonal split]

or moving the information outside of the table altogether into a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different strategies you can apply, depending on the technical constraints that you have. For example, you can make the table more interactive and allow the cell to show occupancy values when you hover over the cell. Given a specific constraint or requirements will allow people to provide a better or less generic response. However, some things to think about include:

- Need to see both values at the same time for the entire heatmap: will this be too much information for the user to process and make it harder to pick up the patterns and trends you are looking for?
- How the information is used to make decisions: what kind of insights are you looking for and how will it help the person viewing the information to make a decision? Are there additional information that will support this decision that is not displayed as well?
- Will there be additional changes to the dataset: are you going to be adding more rows to the heatmap in the future if there are more locations to analyze? Will you try to breakdown the time into finer increments? Will you be adding additional contextual information to filter the information (e.g. days of the week)

I think letting the use case determine the design is better than making a design decision without more details. Sometimes it is a compromise you have to make between the amount of information you want to display and what you actually need to use it for in different situations. If you can update your question I am sure you will get closer to the answer you are looking for.